# Can std::chrono::from_stream convert string to time_point with microseconds accuracy?

Tags: c++, date, parsing, c++20, c++-chrono

**TLDR**:

```
std::chrono::sys_time<std::chrono::microseconds> tTimePoint;
std::istringstream stream("2020-09-16 22:00:00.123456");

std::chrono::from_stream(stream, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tTimePoint);
```

I expected the code above to parse the `.123456` as microseconds. However, when running this `tTimePoint` only contains the date and time excluding subseconds.

***Longer***:

I am using *Visual Studio 2019* with the *\cpplatest* flag on *Windows 10*.
I have a simple input where users can define their datetime format for the input.

Strings can look like `2020-09-16T22:00:00.123456` or `16.09.2020 22:00:00.123456` or any other valid datetime format as long as there's a way of describing it using the qualifiers listed in the [cppreference for std::chrono::from_stream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/from_stream).

Based on the reference and my previous experience with `std::format()`(which uses the same formatting) I would assume that `%S` also parses subseconds.

I have also tried `std::chrono::parse` but this does not state that `%S` would parse subseconds after the decimal. I have tried various different formats and datetime formats to ensure that this issue does not only occur due to some irregular datetime format.

Is this an error in the *cppreference* documentation, is this a not fully implemented feature in the Visual Studio implementation or (most likely) am I just simply missing something obvious about this?

Thank you for any help that I can get!

Comment: Looks like the table entries in cppreference copy those [in the standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/time.parse#tab:time.parse.spec) (in a different order)

Comment: They certainly look very similar. The only difference I can find between these two and the `std::formatter<std::chrono::duration>` is that the latter even states an implicit conversion to microsecond precision. But other than that the description of `%S` is the same for all three...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I can see, VS2019 has a flaw when using `from_stream` and a `time_point` where subseconds are supposed to be used. There is a place in the VS2019 library where it is supposed to deal with it - but it never enters that case.

Fortunately, it works if you use a `duration` instead of a `time_point`, so you *can* work around the problem:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::istringstream stream("2020-09-16 22:00:00.123456");

    std::chrono::sys_time<std::chrono::microseconds> tTimePoint;

    // extract all but the second:  
    std::chrono::from_stream(stream, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:", tTimePoint);

    std::chrono::microseconds micros;

    // extract the second:
    std::chrono::from_stream(stream, "%S", micros);

    // add the duration to the time_point
    tTimePoint += micros;

    std::cout << tTimePoint << '\n';
}
```

[Bugreport](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/std::chrono::from_streamtime_point-fai/1489268?space=8&q=fails+to+extract+subsecond+part&sort=newest&ftype=problem&viewtype=solutions) - Current state: *Fixed In: Visual Studio 2022 version 17.0 Preview 3*

Comment: Thank you for that great suggestion! It's quite cumbersome since the user has free reign how the input format string is defined but my guess is since there's currently no way around it I have to implement this workaround. I think checking for `%S` and `%T` should probably be enough and replace accordingly. 

Anyway, thank you for that workaround!

Comment: @ValentinSagl You're welcome! I wrote a bugreport (added link in the answer). If you login and upvote the bugreport it may get fixed faster :-)

Comment: You beat me to it ;-) I was just looking into how to make a bug report.

Comment: @ValentinSagl In VS2019, top right, there's a little symbol to the right of "Live share". Click on that and select "Report a problem" and you'll get directly to the bug report form.