# C++20: how to convert from std::string to std::chrono::system_clock::time_point with maximum precision?

Tags: c++, stl, format, c++20, c++-chrono

I'm trying to convert some time point to string and back with high precision. I'm using C++20 stl library. It works well with the second precision, but I need milliseconds (or even microseconds) too.

Here is my program:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <format>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    auto tp1 = system_clock::now();
    string src = format("{}", tp1);    // (1)
    stringstream ss{ src };

    system_clock::time_point tp2;
    ss >> parse("%F %T"s, tp2);        // (2)
    bool fail = ss.fail();
    string dst = format("{}", tp2);

    cout << "Source time:    " << src << endl;
    cout << "Converted time: " << dst << (fail ? " (FAILED)"s : " (no fails)"s) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is below:

```
Source time:    2021-09-21 09:31:48.1934653
Converted time: 2021-09-21 09:31:48.0000000 (no fails)
```

Sub-seconds (milliseconds in this case) are lost.

Here is another problem - string (1) does not specify exactly what I need, but string (2) relies on some digits order. How can I specify milliseconds for those lines?

I've tested it on Windows 10 x64, Ms VIsual Studio 2019, Debug x64.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks like a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/a/68559502/576911 (not positive).  This Q/A identifies a bug in VS 2019, has a link to the bug report, and reports that it is fixed in Visual Studio 2022 version 17.0 Preview 3.

Comment: Thanks! Now it's clear :-). Let's wait for new version, and now I'll use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68559502/9072974) workaround.