# Advice on converting timestamp string in "HH:MM:SS.microseconds" format

Tags: c++, string, parsing, timestamp, c++17

I'm given a list of timestamps (suppose we have a ready-made `std::vector<std::string>`) in a string format of a kind `std::vector<std::string> = {"12:27:37.740002", "19:37:17.314002", "20:00:07.140902",...}`. No dates, no timezones. What would be a preferable way to parse these strings to some kind of C++ type (`std::chrono::time_point` ?) to be able to perform some comparisons and sorting later.

For example: compare value, which was parsed from `"20:00:07.140902"` and value, was parsed from `"20:00:07.000000"`.

C++17 is ok, but I can't use any third-party library (Boost, Date etc).
Keeping microseconds precision essential.

Comment: I'd advise parsing them into a `struct` which has four or more members. The first one stands for hours, the second one stands for minutes, the third one is for seconds, and the forth one is for the fractions of the seconds up to the required granularity. For example, `"12:27:37.740002"` would be parsed into `struct TimeStamp{12, 27, 37, 740002}`. It will make comparing easier.

Comment: There's no such thing in the C++ library, and the key words that you used are "any third-party library". This means that this homework assignment expects you to implement all the parsing yourself, character by character, with error checking for invalid input, using logic and looping, and do all the work from start to finish. There are very, very few things in C++ that can be accomplished simply by finding a standard C++ library function that does everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build this functionality completly with C++ standard library functionality.
For parsing the string use std::regex.
For time related datatypes use std::chrono

Example :

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <regex>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

auto parse_to_timepoint(const std::string& input)
{
    // setup a regular expression to parse the input string
    // https://regex101.com/
    // each part between () is a group and will end up in the match
    // [0-2] will match any character from 0 to 2 etc..
    // [0-9]{6} will match exactly 6 digits
    static const std::regex rx{ "([0-2][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])\\.([0-9]{6})" };
    std::smatch match;

    if (!std::regex_search(input, match, rx))
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("input string is not a valid time string");
    }

    // convert each matched group to the corresponding value
    // note match[0] is the complete matched string by the regular expression
    // we only need the groups which start at index 1
    const auto& hours = std::stoul(match[1]);
    const auto& minutes = std::stoul(match[2]);
    const auto& seconds = std::stoul(match[3]);
    const auto& microseconds = std::stoul(match[4]);
    
    // build up a duration
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::duration duration{};
    duration += std::chrono::hours(hours);
    duration += std::chrono::minutes(minutes);
    duration += std::chrono::seconds(seconds);
    duration += std::chrono::microseconds(microseconds);

    // then return a time_point (note this will not help you with correctly handling day boundaries)
    // since there is no date in the input string
    return std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point{ duration };
}

int main()
{
    std::string input1{ "20:00:07.140902" };
    std::string input2{ "20:00:07.000000" };

    auto tp1 = parse_to_timepoint(input1);
    auto tp2 = parse_to_timepoint(input2);

    std::cout << "start time = " << ((tp1 < tp2) ? input1 : input2) << "\n";
    std::cout << "end time = " << ((tp1 >= tp2) ? input1 : input2) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be better to store the result in `std::chrono::microseconds`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why this shouldn't work. Using `std::chrono::from_stream` to parse the string into a time point, then just compare the two time points.

However, I've been trying it now with Visual Studio 2022 17.0.2 (Community Edition) and it fails to parse the string into a `tp`.

There is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68559502/260313) from Ted Lyngmo's talking about a bug (fixed in VS2022 17.0.3) when parsing seconds with subseconds. I have to say though that his solution didn't work for me either in my VS2022.

Anyway, you may want to give it a try.

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>  // boolalpha
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <sstream>  // istringstream
#include <string>

auto parse_string_to_tp(const std::string& str)
{
    std::istringstream iss{ str };
    std::chrono::sys_time<std::chrono::microseconds> tp{};
    std::chrono::from_stream(iss, "%H:%M:%S", tp);  // or simply "%T"
    return tp;
}

int main()
{
    const std::string str1{ "12:27:37.740002" };
    const std::string str2{ "13:00:00.500000" };

    auto tp1{ parse_string_to_tp(str1) };
    auto tp2{ parse_string_to_tp(str2) };

    std::cout << "tp1 < tp2: " << std::boolalpha << (tp1 < tp2) << "\n";
    std::cout << "tp2 < tp1: " << std::boolalpha << (tp2 < tp1) << "\n";
}
```

EDIT: it works if you just use durations instead of time points:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>  // boolalpha
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <sstream>  // istringstream
#include <string>

auto parse_string_to_duration(const std::string& str)
{
    std::istringstream iss{ str };
    std::chrono::microseconds d{};
    std::chrono::from_stream(iss, "%T", d);
    return d;
}

int main()
{
    const std::string str1{ "12:27:37.740002" };
    const std::string str2{ "23:39:48.500000" };

    auto d1{ parse_string_to_duration(str1) };
    auto d2{ parse_string_to_duration(str2) };

    std::cout << "d1 < d2: " << std::boolalpha << (d1 < d2) << "\n";
    std::cout << "d2 < d1: " << std::boolalpha << (d2 < d1) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Right, when there is no date information, you can't form a time_point.  But you can form a duration which you can interpret as "time since midnight", where you get to define midnight yourself.

Comment: Thanks @HowardHinnant, it makes sense.

Comment: Looks like `std::chrono::from_stream` requires C++20 ?

Comment: Yes, requires C++20.  There's a free, open-source, header-only preview of it in date.h here: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date .  The only significant difference are that things are in namespace date instead of namespace std::chrono.