# from_stream not a member of std::chrono

Tags: c++

I am currently working on a small home project for some data processing in C++. My input data contains timestamps, e.g. "2022-02-11T16:05:05+01:00". As I need to do some arithmetic on it (e.g. subtracting and adding minutes), I would like to convert this to a date/time format.

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68559502) on Stack Overflow. I copy-pasted the exact same code into my code editor (Visual Studio 17.0.6), which produces buckets of errors, two of these being:

```
C2039   'sys_time': is not a member of 'std::chrono'
C2039   'from_stream': is not a member of 'std::chrono'
```

I then tried [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/) with the latest GCC and Clang compilers, again with many errors (although the sys_time error has disappeared).

I haven't used C++ that much in the last couple of years, so I am not entirely familiar with
all the additions to the recent versions. However, I see that the chrono library has been implemented in all of these compilers as part of the C++20 additions. Why do I keep getting these errors?

Comment: Are you compiling with at least C++20? Visual Studio hides that away in the project properties if you're using msbuild.

Comment: [works for me](https://godbolt.org/z/rWc18c69P), see "Calendar and timezone" at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support. MSVC has the only complete implementation, libc++ and libstdc++ aren't complete yet

Comment: I faced the same problem recently... Calendar and many time related functions are not yet implemented. Take a look at HowardHinnat implementation.

Answer (score 4):

There is a free, open source preview that I can recommend: [Take a look at HowardHinnant](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date)

```
std::chrono::sys_time<std::chrono::microseconds> timestamp;
std::stringstream ss = foo();
ss >> date::parse("%Y-%m-%d %T", timestamp);
```

Answer (score 2):

This part of the chrono library is new with C++20, and has only been implemented by Visual Studio 19.x to date.

I was about to recommend my free open-source preview, but I see Orkhan has already done that for me. :-)